# Converting a Range list into a Flat list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, function

I am trying to change the structure of a Legend list that started out as a range (1-2=blue, 2-3=red,etc.) into a flat list of words ("blah"=blue, "peek"=red).

The problem I'm having is I need to figure out a way to keep the number system in place while replacing that meaning with text. Moreover, I need the corresponding color to be next to the text like so...

```
(color)text<br>
(color)text<br>
(color)text
```

**What is set in place is (This determines the color)**

```
function getColor(d) {
    return d === 5 ? '#3e9936' :
    d === 4  ? '#9dcc00' :
    d === 3  ? '#f7ef00' :
    d === 2  ? '#ed5d13' :
    d === 1  ? '#ba212a' :
               '#a1a1a1';
}
```

**This is what what will show up on the map and determines the structure**

```
legend.onAdd = function (map) {

    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
        grades = [1,2, 3, 4, 5],
        labels = ["Pro-LEED","LEED-equivalent","No State-level","Anti-LEED","Anti-LEED Pending"],
        from, to;

    for (var i = "Pro-LEED"; i === labels.length; i++) {
        from = labels[i];
        to = labels[i];

        grades.push(
            '<i style="background:' + getColor(to + '"Pro-LEED"') + '"></i> ' +
            (/*only to check*/to ? to : 'br') +
            ((/*both to and from check*/from)?'':'') + 
            (/*only from check*/from ? from : '+'));
    }
    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
    return div;
};
```

Right now all I'm getting is a List of Texts and not the colors that should be next to each word.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash-array and look up the value directly, without a function:

```
var myData = [];
myData["Pro-LEED"] = "#3e9936";
```

...then...

```
'<i style="background:' + myData["Pro-LEED"] + '"></i> '
```

Comment: I am very new to this so please excuse my ignorance, but however would /do you continue setting up the list for the legend. The 'to' and 'from' part is lost on me